# How to use apply for functions that need "data$varname" vs functions that need just "varname"

Tags: r, apply, sapply

Relatively new R user here that has been wrestling with making code more efficient for future uses, mainly trying out functions from the apply family.

Right now, I have a script in which I pull means from a large number of variables by (manually) creating a list of variable names and passing it into a sapply.

So this is an example of how I made a list of variable names and how I passed that into sapply

```
vars <- c("data$age", "data$gender", "data$PCLR")
means <- sapply(vars, fmean, data$group, na.rm=TRUE)
```

However, I now want to use a function that uses the argument format of *function(varname, data)*, so I can't actually use that list of names I made. What I'm trying to do:

```
krusk <- sapply(vars, function(x) kruskal.test(x ~ group, data))
```

I feel like there is a way to pass my variable names into functions I have been completely overlooking, instead manually creating lists. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: use `reformulate` to turn strings into a formula: `kruskal.test(reformulate('group', x), data)`

Answer (score 0):

This can work using `iris` dataset as `data` similar to great suggestion from **@deschen**:

```
#Vars
vars <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
#Code
krusk <- sapply(vars, function(x) kruskal.test(iris[[x]] ~ iris[['Species']]))
```

Output:

```
krusk
          Sepal.Length                     Sepal.Width                     
statistic 96.93744                         63.57115                        
parameter 2                                2                               
p.value   8.918734e-22                     1.569282e-14                    
method    "Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test"   "Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test"  
data.name "iris[[x]] by iris[["Species"]]" "iris[[x]] by iris[["Species"]]"
```

Comment: Mine actually didn't work. I also might be mistaken but I read the TOs question in a way that the requirement for the `vars` vector would still be that it contains the data object + the names, so in your example `vars <- c("iris$Sepal.Length", "iris$Sepal.Width")`.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close! You can do it by subsetting the data frame that you input to `sapply` using your `vars` vector, and changing the formula in `kruskal.test`:

```
vars <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
sapply(iris[, vars], function(x) kruskal.test(x ~ iris$Species))
```

Answer (score 0):

R is a very diverse coding language and there will ultimately be many ways to do the same thing. Some functions expect a more standard evaluation while others may use NSE (non-standard evaluation).

However, you seem to be asking about functions who just expect a single vector as impute as opposed to functions who have a `data` argument, in which you use `variable` as opposed to `data$variable`.

I have a few sidebars before I give some advice

### Sidebar 1 - S3 Methods

While this may be besides the point in regards to the question, the function `kruskal.test` has two methods.

```
methods("kruskal.test")
#[1] kruskal.test.default* kruskal.test.formula*
#see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

Which method is used depends on the class of the first argument in the function. In this example you are passing a formula expression in which the `data` argument is necessary, whereas the default method just requires `x` and `g` arguments (which you could probably use your original pipelines).

So, if you're used to doing something one way, be sure to check the documentation of a function has different dispatch methods that will work for you.

### Sidebar 2 - Data Frames

Data frames are really just a collection of vectors. The difference between `f(data$variable)` and `f(x = variable, data = data)`, is that in the first the user explicitly tells R where to find the vector, while in the latter, it is up the the function `f` to evaluate `x` in the context of `data`.
I bring this up because of what I said in the beginning - there are many ways to do the same thing. So its generally up to you what you want your standard to be.

If you prefer to be explicit

```
vars <- c("data$age", "data$gender", "data$PCLR")
means <- sapply(vars, fmean, data$group, na.rm=TRUE)
krusk <- sapply(vars, kruskal.test, g = data$group)
```

or you can write your functions in which they are expected to be evaluated within a certain `data.frame` object

```
vars <- c("age", "gender", "PCLR")
means <- sapply(vars, function(x, id, data) fmean(data[[x]], id = data[[id]], na.rm=T), id = "group", data = data)
krusk <- sapply(vars, function(x, id, data) kruskal.test(data[[x]], data[[id]]), id = "group", data = data)
```

## My Advice

I recommend looking into the following packages `dplyr`, `tidyr`, `purrr`. I'm sure there are a few things in these packages that will make your life easier.

For example, you have expressed having to manually make list before doing the `sapply`. In `dplyr` package you can possibly circumvent this if there is a condition to filter on.

```
data %>%
    group_by(group) %>% #groups data
    summarise_if(is.numeric, mean, na.rm = TRUE) #applys mean to every column that is a numeric vector
```

And similarly, we can summarise the results of the `kurskal.test` function if we reshape the data a bit.

```
data %>% 
     group_by(group) %>% #grouping to retain column in the next select statement
     select_if(is.numeric) %>% # selecting all numeric columns
     pivot_longer(cols = -group) %>% # all columns except "group" will be reshaped. Column names are stored in `name`, and values are stored in `values`
     group_by(name) %>% #regroup on name variable (old numeric columns)
     summarise(krusk = list(kruskal.test(value ~ as.factor(group)))) #perform test
```

I've only mentioned `purrr` because you can almost drop and replace all `apply` style functions with their `map` variants. `purrr` is very consistent across its function variants with a lot of options to control the output type.

I hope this helps and wish you luck on your coding adventures.

Comment: Hey Justin, thanks for this answer! I hadn't seen that other way of doing the kruskal.test so that will definitely help with how i structured my vars-variable this time. I actually do use dplyr a lot already, but I see that I need to familiarize myself more with how to use the functions associated. I actually have a bit of code using 'summarise(across(starts_with("Pect")', as all the variables I need to look at start with those words (so not necessarily only numeric variables). But I'll keep digging into that 'select_if' function as well!

Comment: Did it! End result for my code was:
krusk <- data_clean %>% group_by(cutoff_26) %>% select(starts_with("Pect")) %>% pivot_longer(cols =-cutoff_26) %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(krusk = list(kruskal.test(value ~ as.factor(cutoff_26))))

Thanks so much for your help!